# Select Count stored procedure with dynamic query not working correctly

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

-I'm trying to execute a stored procedure that should returns me the result of a Count, but it gives me the following error(it's in portuguese):

```
2019-04-01 10:13:49.215  WARN 7068 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 214, SQLState: S0002
2019-04-01 10:13:49.216 ERROR 7068 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : O procedimento espera o parâmetro '@statement' do tipo 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.
```

-I dont quite understand, because the only parameter that i setted is the table name, which i'm passing on my repository execution code.

-This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_verificarTabelaCadMov] (
    @NomeTabela VARCHAR(20)

)   
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @Comando Varchar(1000)
Declare @Resultado INT;

Set @Comando = 'SELECT @Resultado = COUNT(*) FROM sysobjects WHERE nome = ' + QUOTENAME(@NomeTabela)

exec sp_executesql @Comando , N'@Resultado INT OUTPUT', @Resultado = @Resultado OUTPUT

SELECT @Resultado

END;

GO
```

-This is my execution in my Repository:

```
@Query(value = "EXECUTE usp_verificarTabelaCadMov :tabela", nativeQuery = true)
public Integer verificarTabela(@Param("tabela") String tabela);
```

-In my controller:

```
                    String tabela = ("M00"+(String.valueOf(Math.round(funcionario.getEmpresa().getCodigo())))+anoInicio+mesAtual);
                    if (eventoEspelhoPontoRepository.verificarTabela(tabela) > 1) {
                        registros.addAll(eventoEspelhoPontoRepository.findAllRegistrosByFuncionarioTableUnica(
                                tabela, dataInicioString, dataFimString, funcionario.getCracha()));
                    }
```

EDIT1 - what i'm trying to do here, is select a row of tables, but sometimes some of the tables doesn't exist, so i'm trying to do a verification if the table exists, and if it does, it should execute the Select * from that table, otherwise, should ignore. This is the only way i found to do it, if anyone has a better way please help me.

Btw, this is my select mentioned above, I tried to verify the existance of the table with the clause IF EXISTS but it doest work, I keep getting the error COULD NOT EXTRACT RESULT SET on my main program.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_listarRegistrosMov]
    --PARÂMETROS
    @NomeTabela VARCHAR(20),
    @DataInicial VARCHAR(20),
    @DataFinal VARCHAR(20),
    @Cracha FLOAT

AS  

IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = @NomeTabela AND xtype = 'U')

BEGIN

Declare @Comando Varchar(1000)

Set @Comando = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @NomeTabela + ' WHERE mov_data BETWEEN ''' + @DataInicial + ''' AND ''' + @DataFinal + ''' AND mov_cracha = ' + CAST(@Cracha AS VARCHAR(50))

Exec(@Comando)

END



GO
```

EDIT 2: I tried using OBJECT_ID in the same sp also:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(@NomeTabela) IS NOT NULL
```

But always get the error:

```
2019-04-01 11:18:03.147  WARN 7068 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2019-04-01 11:18:03.148 ERROR 7068 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The statement did not return a result set.
```

Comment: This sure looks like SQL Server code.   Are you sure it's on a MySQL database?

Comment: Sorry wrong tag, didn't noticed that

Comment: @Comando should be of type NVARCHAR, not VARCHAR.

Comment: @Morten same error after setting N'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, I had to:

1 - Change my stored procedure to this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_verificarTabelaCadMov
      @NomeTabela VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @Exists INT

      IF EXISTS(SELECT name
                        FROM sysobjects
                        WHERE name = @NomeTabela)
      BEGIN
            SET @Exists = 1
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
            SET @Exists = 0
      END

      RETURN @Exists
END
```

2 - Change my call on Repository to this:

```
@Query(value = "Declare @Exists int "
        + "Exec @Exists = usp_verificarTabelaCadMov :tabela"
        + " Select @Exists", nativeQuery = true)
```

RESULT: it's checking whether the table exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_verificarTabelaCadMov
(
  @NomeTabela VARCHAR(20)
)
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Comando NVARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE @Resultado INT;

    SET @Resultado = -1

        -- Or set to NULL depending on how you would like to handle table existence in the application code;
        --SET @Resultado = NULL

    IF OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@NomeTabela), 'U') IS NOT NULL
      BEGIN
        SET @Comando = N'SELECT @Resultado = COUNT(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@NomeTabela);

        EXEC sys.sp_executesql
          @Comando
          , N'@Resultado INT OUTPUT'
          , @Resultado OUTPUT;
      END;

    SELECT @Resultado AS resultado;
  END;
```

So depending on your choice how to handle table existence, calling

```
EXEC dbo.usp_verificarTabelaCadMov @NomeTabela = 'thistabledoesNOTexist';
```

would return -1 or NULL (see stored proc comment) and

```
EXEC dbo.usp_verificarTabelaCadMov @NomeTabela = 'thistableDOESexist';
```

would return a value > -1.

Comment: the @NomeTabela parameter is the table i'm verifying existance in sysobjects

Comment: I saw that in your original code, however like I said, what I would do is do the same check but then via IF OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@NomeTabela), 'U') IS NOT NULL. As I understood your code you are mainly interested in the rowcount if the table exists?

Comment: actually just the check, if table exists or not.. if it doesnt, it should skip the select and skip the addAll on my List, and proceed to the next table you got it?